# Reset laptop from Windows 11 to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-11

I upgraded to Windows 11 and then regretted it, some of the apps I need weren't supported yet.

**How do I reset it to Windows 10?**

I've tried Settings > Update & Security > Recovery > Reset this PC, it brings me back to a fresh install of Windows 11.

Comment: There should be an option to "Go Back" on that same page (System - Recovery)... if that option is no longer there.. then your only option is to get a Windows 10 USB and do a full reinstall..

Comment: If you have already Reset Windows 11 it’s impossible to revert back to Windows 10 without performing a complete clean Windows 10 install. You only had 10 days by default to revert back to Windows 10. You should have asked for our help instead of using the Reset option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing Reset, you have deleted the upgrade information from Windows 10
to Windows 11. You now have a fresh Windows 11 installation.

Therefore you no longer have the option to go back to Windows 10,
as the Windows 10 installation doesn't exist any more.

Your only option is to download an installation ISO of Windows 10
from Microsoft, burn it to USB, boot it and install.
I would also advise to reformat the disk, so as to avoid having
leftovers from Windows 11 in your Windows 10.

Backup any data you have on the disk before doing the above.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can Go back from Windows 11 to Windows 10. when you do that within 10 days, you will not lose any files. However, after the 10-days period, you need to clean install Windows 10 since the Roll back or Go back option will be gone.

The post below can be a guide.

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-downgrade-from-windows-11-to-windows-10

Before getting started, you should know that downgrading to Windows 10 will remove all apps you may have installed and changes made in the settings. However, you can set things up once you have a fully functional Windows 10 computer.

Comment: You have literally just copied and pasted text from a website and pasted it into your answer.  You must both cite and quote text from a third-party.  Text from another website, without quoting that text, is considered to be plagiarism. The entirety of your answer is the content from the article.

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing). You must block quote text that has been written by some else.